# Area under Precision-Recall Curve (AUC of PR-curve) and Average Precision (AP)

Tags: scikit-learn, precision-recall, auc, average-precision

Is Average Precision (AP) the Area under Precision-Recall Curve (AUC of PR-curve)  ?

**EDIT:**

here is some comment about difference in PR AUC and AP.

> The AUC is obtained by trapezoidal interpolation of the precision. An
>   alternative and usually almost equivalent metric is the Average
>   Precision (AP), returned as info.ap. This is the average of the
>   precision obtained every time a new positive sample is recalled. It is
>   the same as the AUC if precision is interpolated by constant segments
>   and is the definition used by TREC most often.

http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/plots-rank.html

Moreover, the [auc](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.auc.html) and the [average_precision_score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.average_precision_score.html) results are not the same in scikit-learn. This is strange, because in the documentation we have:

> Compute average precision (AP) from prediction scores This score
>   corresponds to the area under the precision-recall curve.

here is the code:

```
# Compute Precision-Recall and plot curve
precision, recall, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(y_test, clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1])
area = auc(recall, precision)
print "Area Under PR Curve(AP): %0.2f" % area  #should be same as AP?

print 'AP', average_precision_score(y_test, y_pred, average='weighted')
print 'AP', average_precision_score(y_test, y_pred, average='macro')
print 'AP', average_precision_score(y_test, y_pred, average='micro')
print 'AP', average_precision_score(y_test, y_pred, average='samples')
```

for my classifer I have something like:

```
Area Under PR Curve(AP): 0.65
AP 0.676101781304
AP 0.676101781304
AP 0.676101781304
AP 0.676101781304
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Short answer is: **YES**. Average Precision is a single number used to summarise a Precision-Recall curve:

[image]

You can approximate the integral (area under the curve) with:

[image]

Please take a look at [this link](https://sanchom.wordpress.com/tag/average-precision/) for a good explanation.

Comment: What about this comment? "The AUC is obtained by trapezoidal interpolation of the precision. An alternative and usually almost equivalent metric is the Average Precision (AP), returned as info.ap. This is the average of the precision obtained every time a new positive sample is recalled. It is the same as the AUC if precision is interpolated by constant segments and is the definition used by TREC most often." http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/plots-rank.html

Comment: I think `the average of the precision obtained every time a new positive sample is recalled` refers to **Interpolated average precision** explained in the link I gave. Some authors choose an alternate approximation that is called the **interpolated average precision**. Confusingly, they still call it average precision.

Comment: a few quick questions: 1) why coordinate (recall=0, precision=1)? makes no sense to me at all.  2) as you might observe, if we lower the classifier's threshold, more results could be returned, and as a consequence, recall might not increase, but precision could vary, for example, with 2 positive items in total, here is the ranked results = [False, True, False, False, True], so p-r pairs = [(p=0, r=0), (1/2, 1/2), (1/3, 1/2), (1/4, 1/2), (2/5, 2/2)], as you can see, for r=1/2, there're 3 p (i.e. 1/2, 1/3, 1/4), just like in your graph at r=0.8, it's ok just plot them at the same x axis?

Comment: @Zhubarb Most of the credible articles mention that `the average of the precision obtained every time a new positive sample is recalled` is average precision and this is approximated by the area under the uninterpolated precision-recall curve - https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/evaluation-of-ranked-retrieval-results-1.html, https://engineering.purdue.edu/kak/SignificanceTesting.pdf and wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_measures_(information_retrieval)#Average_precision). While the article you shared mentions opposite of that.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning for future readers that the AP is not equal to the AUPRC for the scikit learn implementation, from the docs "This implementation is not interpolated and is different from computing the area under the precision-recall curve with the trapezoidal rule, which uses linear interpolation and can be too optimistic." https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.average_precision_score.html#sklearn.metrics.average_precision_score

Answer (score 4):

`average_precision_score` function expect confidence or probability as second parameter.

so you should use it as below,

```
average_precision_score(y_test, clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1])
```

and then it's same result of `auc` function.

Comment: Different examples in WEKA software and scikit-learn provide CLF score but not AUC. Can it be that this CLF score is actually somehow related to AUC or even be AUC?